# how to get service container logs and upload them as artifacts in gitlab

Tags: logging, service, containers, gitlab-ci-runner, artifacts

**Background:**
I use gitlab-ee of v13.11.4 and also have gitlab runners(both helper and builder) configured and deployed in a k8s cluster.  
**Problem:**
When a pipeline is triggered for a project in gitlab the jobs pick up a runner and finish the job and while job is running I want to capture those logs and upload them as artifacts so developers can download them?  
I do have idea of kubernetes commands to get logs of a container but unable to approach the above problem

```
kubectl logs -c svc-0  -n ${RUNNER_NAMESPACE} $(hostname) > svc0.log
kubectl logs -c svc-1  -n ${RUNNER_NAMESPACE} $(hostname) > svc1.log
```

How can I get the logs while job is running and also upload them as artifacts in post-build ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the service container logs of a job then use it like below in .gitlab-ci.yml

```
sample_job:
  script:
    - kubectl logs ${HOSTNAME} -n ${RUNNER_NAMESPACE} -c svc-0 > svc0.log
```

${HOSTNAME} is a gitlab environment variable which gives pod's name where job is running.
${RUNNER_NAMESPACE} is namespace where your gitlab runners are deployed in k8s

Note: if you think there might be multiple containers then have for loop running for all the svc-* containers in the runner pod(${HOSTNAME}) of job.